# Openpyxl: Appending lists from dictionaries to end of matching excel rows

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a dictionary of lists:

```
dictofannotations = {
'5988': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1'],
'5989': ['2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
'5982': ['1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1']
}
```

These dictionary keys can be found in one column (9 or J) of an excel file. When a match in the excel document is found for the dictionary key, I want to append the list (one list item to one cell) to the end of the matching row.

I'm close, but not able to write to the workbook.

```
filename = 'dataset.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Dataset')


for x in range(1,7582):
##7582 is the number of rows in the document, 1 should ignore the header

    if ws.cell(row = x, column = 9).value in dictofannotations:
        ws.append(dictofannotations[ws.cell(row = x, column = 9)])

wb.save("finaldataset.withannotations.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows do not exist physically for openpyxl so you cannot append cells to an existing worksheet. Instead you must create/overwrite the cells manually.

The logic for this would be something like:

```
if cell in dictofannotations:
     values = dictofannotations[key]
     for idx, value in values:
          ws.cell(row=x, col=9+idx, value=value)
```